# Server hanging when serving random file on page load

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server, fedora, performance-tuning

I'm optimising a website, and the problem I'm facing with now is server related. During page load, there are about 40-50 requests sent to server (depending on the page), and in every case, server hangs for about 5-6 seconds on a certain file (images mostly, cause css and js is getting merged), or two or three.. take a look at firebug screenshot to get a better idea what I'm talking about

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDhih.png

(there are 90 requests here cause js and css are not merged).
website is [Bigelow Chemists](http://www.bigelowchemists.com) . Any idea what might be causing this. I can take a deeper look, I just need a hint at what might be the cause for such behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your web server is not configured to handle that number of requests.

- Enable **Keep Alive**

  > ```
  > # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
  > # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
  > #
  > KeepAlive On
  >
  > #
  > # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
  > # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
  > # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
  > #
  > MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
  > ```
- Adjust you server parameters to have a **sufficient number of processes** to handle concurrent requests

  > ```
  > # prefork MPM
  > # StartServers: number of server processes to start
  > # MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
  > # MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
  > # MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
  > # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
  > <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  >     StartServers          5
  >     MinSpareServers       5
  >     MaxSpareServers      50
  >     MaxClients          150
  >     MaxRequestsPerChild   0
  > </IfModule>
  >
  > # worker MPM
  > # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
  > # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
  > # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
  > # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
  > # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
  > # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
  > <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
  >     StartServers          5
  >     MaxClients          150
  >     MinSpareThreads      25
  >     MaxSpareThreads      75
  >     ThreadsPerChild      25
  >     MaxRequestsPerChild   0    
  > </IfModule>
  > ```

Comment: As I understand, these two MPM modules should not be used in the same time. I should be using only one, right? Which one do you recommend? We have xlarge amazon server. Thx